# ReactJS dropzone upload file via webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, selenium

Try to upload image into dropzone with selenium webDriver. Already realize it for site dropzonejsdotcom, but if i try use script for reactJS dropzone (http://reactdropzone.azurewebsites.net/example/) I get a message: "unknown error: Dropzone is not defined".

```
JavascriptExecutor executor;

public ReactDrpzn() {
    Configuration.browser = "chrome";
    this.executor = (JavascriptExecutor) WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver();
}
private By dropzone = By.cssSelector(".filepicker.dropzone.dz-clickable");

@Test
public void drzon() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    open("http://reactdropzone.azurewebsites.net/example");
    $(dropzone).hover();
    String script = "var myZone, blob, base64Image; myZone = Dropzone.forElement('.filepicker.dropzone.dz-clickable');" +
            "base64Image = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAO0AAABQCAYAAAD1GfIkAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsIAAA7CARUoSoAAAAEGSURBVHhe7dPBCcAwAAMxp/vv3ObRJQ4kMJ7gzrb3Doh4/gciRAsxooUY0UKMaCFGtBAjWogRLcSIFmJECzGihRjRQoxoIUa0ECNaiBEtxIgWYkQLMaKFGNFCjGghRrQQI1qIES3EiBZiRAsxooUY0UKMaCFGtBAjWogRLcSIFmJECzGihRjRQoxoIUa0ECNaiBEtxIgWYkQLMaKFGNFCjGghRrQQI1qIES3EiBZiRAsxooUY0UKMaCFGtBAjWogRLcSIFmJECzGihRjRQoxoIUa0ECNaiBEtxIgWYkQLMaKFGNFCjGghRrQQI1qIES3EiBZiRAsxooUY0UKMaCFGtBAjWkjZPk/PAZ8fwt/rAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';" +
            "function base64toBlob(r,e,n){e=e||\"\",n=n||512;for(var t=atob(r),a=[],o=0;o<t.length;o+=n){for(var l=t.slice(o,o+n),h=new Array(l.length),b=0;b<l.length;b++)h[b]=l.charCodeAt(b);var v=new Uint8Array(h);a.push(v)}var c=new Blob(a,{type:e});return c}" +
            "blob = base64toBlob(base64Image, 'image / png');" +
            "blob.name = 'file.png';" +
            "myZone.addFile(blob);";

    executor.executeScript(script);
    Thread.sleep(3000);//смотрим результат
}
```

U can import maven from here https://github.com/SaneQ/Drpzn

Comment: The reason is this won't work in browser console also. The DropZone object is inside the react context and the object is not available in main window. So you need to somehow first expose or get this object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, two steps:

- find the element:
- send the key with the location of the file you want to upload.

JavaScript:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

let driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('http://reactdropzone.azurewebsites.net/example/');
driver.findElement(By.xpath('.//input[@type="file"]')).sendKeys('full_path_to_your_file.png');
```

Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://reactdropzone.azurewebsites.net/example/')
input_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@type="file"]')
input_field.send_keys('full_path_to_your_file.png')
```

Comment: This is correct but the dropzone component must have an `onKeyDown` prop,,

Comment: Is there a CSS alternative to use xpath?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found easy way to upload image in react dropzone.
React creates hiden inputs in DOM (Body > input)
And after that I just use selenium sendKeys("pathToImg")